# Inner product and symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

It is easy to show that if $B$ is a symmetric matrix then $\langle Bx,y\rangle = \langle x,By\rangle$:

$$\langle Bx,y\rangle = (Bx)^Ty=x^TB^Ty=x^TBy=\langle x,By\rangle.$$

But how to prove the opposite way, that is, if we assume that $\langle Bx,y\rangle = \langle x,By\rangle$, then $B$ is a symmetric matrix?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Let $x$ and $y$ be standard basis vectors.  Then what are $\langle Bx,y\rangle$ and $\langle x,By\rangle$ in terms of the entries of $B$?